# How I can increase the quantity of a specific field(product) in a specific field (schedule) in MongoDB using Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to increase the quantity of a specific product in a specific schedule in MongoDB using node js. I used the $inc operator with a value of 1, which increments the "quantity" field of the matched product by 1.Increase the quantity by a create new field with value.

```js
    {
            "_id": "64045c9f042203d82d3f2579",
            "uid": 3244937753011,
            "phoneNumber": 50115455,
            "email": "example@gmail.com",
            "verified": true,
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "_id": "641c1e9682c4dde5b41814ee",
                    "scheduleTitle": "with status valuuuuuuuuuuuu",
                    "deliveryDate": "Mar 23, 2023",
                    "deliveryLocation": "home",
                    "preferedTime": "3:40 PM",
                    "description": "",
                    "createAt": "Mar 23, 2023 @ 3:40 PM",
                    "status": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "641c1ec082c4dde5b41814ef",
                    "scheduleTitle": "amr 1st schedule",
                    "deliveryDate": "Mar 23, 2023",
                    "deliveryLocation": "arekta notun address",
                    "preferedTime": "3:41 PM",
                    "description": "",
                    "createAt": "Mar 23, 2023 @ 3:41 PM",
                    "status": false,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "productId":"63f6f44cd9cbc8eaf3e6b45",
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "price": 500
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "641c1ed682c4dde5b41814f0",
                    "scheduleTitle": "amr 1st schedule",
                    "deliveryDate": "Mar 23, 2023",
                    "deliveryLocation": "arekta notun address",
                    "preferedTime": "3:41 PM",
                    "description": "",
                    "createAt": "Mar 23, 2023 @ 3:41 PM",
                    "status": false,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "productId": "967endfy77draf3ea7",
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "price": 560
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `arrayFilters` feature in MongoDB `updateOne` operation.

From [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateOne):

> Optional. An array of filter documents that determine which array elements to modify for an update operation on an array field.
> In the update document, use the $[] filtered positional operator to define an identifier, which you then reference in the array filter documents. You cannot have an array filter document for an identifier if the identifier is not included in the update document.

Here is a final working query:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "64045c9f042203d82d3f2579",
  "schedule._id": "641c1ec082c4dde5b41814ef",
  "schedule.products.productId": "63f6f44cd9cbc8eaf3e6b45"
},
{
  $inc: {
    "schedule.$[scheduleElement].products.$[productElement].quantity": 1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "scheduleElement._id": "641c1ec082c4dde5b41814ef"
    },
    {
      "productElement.productId": "63f6f44cd9cbc8eaf3e6b45"
    }
  ]
})
```

You can debug a query in the online MongoDB playground here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jicAVzFsoSj